# How do I remove or relocate C:\wmpub\wmiislog directory et al?

Tags: windows-server-2003

After installing Windows Server 2003 R2, I can see the following directories in the C:\ directory

- C:\FPSE_search
- C:\Inetpub
- C:\wmpub
- C:\wmpub\wsiislog

I would like to move all of the above to locations of my choosing. I know how to move `C:\Inetpub`, however, I could not find anything for the other folders.

Can someone point me in the right direction, or maybe suggest a solution? Please feel free to also comment on whether or not this is a good practice.

NB: I have not accepted the only response I have gotten because I do not yet know how to do move C:\wmpub and C:\FPSE_search folders to a different location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**C:\wmpub** is created by the OCM (optional components manager) at OS install time and is there by default on every install of 2003 Server. It is locked by the winlogon.exe process and will be recreated if deleted.  This behavior is by design and there is no supported way to remove the folder.

Technically it is the directory that will be used by certain Windows Media Services components if they are ever installed, but because of the way the OCM installation .inf files are set, the folder is created whether or not Windows Media Services are installed.

**C:\FPSE_search** has to do with Frontpage Server Extensions. If you uninstalled it, I suppose it could be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any good reasons on why this should be moved, it's not good practice. This directory will house the Windows Media Server setup logging application extension (`wmisslog.dll`) in the folder and if another application tries to access it's default location it could cause a multitude of other problems if it isn't there.

Comment: One of the reasons some people have tried to move it is because this folder is constantly in use and backups have failed for some people due to open file handles.

Personally, I do not like the idea of applications installing themselves in C:\. If an application really doesn't like being installed in a path with spaces (like "C:\Program Files") then I like to install it in another location such as D:\ or E:\.

(to be continued)

Comment: (continued)

My expectation is that Microsoft's products are capable of handling installation paths with spaces and that a procedure to move these folders will include changes so that any correctly written applications can find any required files contained within these folders.

In my current situation, I am not using Windows Media Streaming services, or Front Page Extensions. I am only using Internet Information Services. IIS uses C:\Inetput by default. I do have the correct procedure for moving that folder.